# Pytest: associate parameterized fixtures with expected results

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

Say I have the following test:

```python
@pytest.fixture(params=['a'])
def ascii(request):
    return ord(request.param)

def test_ascii(ascii):
    assert ascii == 97
```

This works great. Now say I'd like to add `'b'` as a parameter. Ideally I could just decorate the test with something like `@pytest.mark.parametrize('ascii_val', [97, 98])`, add `ascii_val` as an agrument to the test and assert `ascii == ascii_val`. Pytest, however, would also assert `'a'` against 98 and `'b'` against 97.

Is there any way for me to associate `'a'` with 97 and `'b'` with 98? I'm asking because I'm going to have a lot of tests like `test_ascii` where I'll be checking that some input consistently outputs the same output given different analysis techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for the simple example you're giving, why use a parametrized fixture instead of parametrizing your test?

Something like this should work:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('char, expected', [('a', 97), ('b', 98)])
def test_ascii(char, expected):
    assert ord(char) == expected
```

If you really wanted to use a fixture, you could always return a `(char, expected)` tuple from it and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

A further example, expanding on the notion in the other answer about embedding the expected responses within the parameterization.  it is possible to stuff in individual values or just a dictionary that can be used within several assert statements.  Admittedly, this is a little contrived because the function under test only returns 1 value, for which an equality test is fairly conclusive....  But for more complex functions, I find this approach workable:

```
import pytest

data = [
    {
        'case': 'letter a',
        'ltr': 'a',
        'expected': {'val': 97, 'greater': False}
    },
    {
        'case': 'letter b',
        'ltr': 'b',
        'expected': {'val': 98, 'greater': True}
    }
]


@pytest.fixture()
def ascii(request):
    return ord(request.param['ltr']), request.param['expected']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('ascii', argvalues=data, indirect=True, ids=[t['case'] for t in data])
def test_ascii(ascii):
    ascii_val, expected = ascii
    assert ascii_val == expected['val']
    greater = ascii_val > 97.5
    assert greater == expected['greater']
```